# How do you get ray gun mark 2

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

How do you get the ray gun mark 2

Comment: The purpose of the question body is *not* to simply copy the title into. You should use it to give more details regarding the question you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

From the [wiki](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Ray_Gun_Mark_II)

It is acquired randomly from the [Mystery Box](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Mystery_Box) for 950 with the following restrictions

> The Ray Gun Mark II is a wonder weapon that was released alongside the Zombies map, Buried, and is featured in **all Zombies maps in Call of Duty: Black Ops II (only if the player has downloaded the Vengeance map pack)**.